# FilerException when building Java EE 6 Project

Tags: netbeans, java-ee-6

I have a Java EE 6 Project in Netbeans 7 which runs fine when I compile and start it in the IDE. However, when I clean and build the project, I am getting a

> `java.lang.RuntimeException`: `javax.annotation.processing.FilerException`: Attempt to recreate a file for type {`myclass`}

(where `myclass` is always a JPA entity class).

Which entity class it is changes if I change something in the code.

I have no clue what might cause this error - can anyone provide an idea what to look at.

The only extra lib I am using is Velocity.

**Update**: I am using two persistence units on the same database, one 'normal' one and one non transactional one. The non-transactional one I use for logging things to the database; with a commit after each insert of a log event.

When I change that and only use the one 'normal' PU, the project compiles fine. Could it be that the two PUs interfere with some optimization done by eclipselink?

Here is the beginning of the stack trace:

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type de.guj.contenthub.ftdts.entity.AgofEntry_
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:625)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:554)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:699)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:981)
    at com.sun.tools.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, the problem is that I use one and the same entity class in two different persistence units. I am not sure whether this forbidden by JPA in general or is only a problem with eclipselink.

One 'solution' I found then is to duplicate my entity class. Not nice, but works for now.

More answers still welcome.

Answer (score 30):

Having two persistence units using the same Entity class did seem to be the problem.

In my case I had one unit for querying data and the other for authentication.  The one for authentication does not need to know about my Entity classes, so in Netbeans I had to uncheck the "Include All Entity Classes in "MyWebServiceProject" Module".
Or add:

> `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>`

to the web.xml file for that persistence unit.

Answer (score 20):

I got this solved by setting

```
<property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="foobar"/>
```

for each persistence unit in persistence.xml. The value has to be unique for each unit. The classes are then generated into different packages, eg. `com.mycompany.foo.PojoOne_` and `com.mycompany.bar.PojoOne_` instead of just `com.mycompany.PojoOne_`.

[Source](http://blog.universaliun.com/tecnologias-informacion/development/java/java-maven-and-jpa-eclipselink-error-javax-annotation-processing-filerexception-attempt-to-recreate-a-file/)

Answer (score 7):

The answser is to make this in the persistence.xml file;

```
<persistence-unit name="prod_PU">
   <properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="prod"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="dev_PU">
   <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="dev"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

For example, the packages for the entity1 will be generated as :

```
entity1.prod
entity1.dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue, and have diagnosed it a bit to the point that I have an ugly workaround that is not ideal.

I have two persistence units in my persistence.xml: one for testing and one for the actual production build.

The reason I have that is because if I use the preferred method of putting another persistence.xml under the src/tests/resources/META-INF folder, the tests fail because the generated classes get put in a the target/generated-sources/test-annotations folder and don't end up in the right place in the classpath once they compile.

The issue is that if both have the "exclude-unlisted-classes" set to true, the javac compiler tries to recreate the annotation classes during the compiler:compile and of course fails on the second PU because the classes have already been created.

So to get this to work, I set the "exclude-unlisted-classes" to false for one of the PU's, which gets me the generated meta classes, and the tests fail (because the PU doesn't include the required entities).

I then flip the flag back to true, and run the build again. Since the classes have already been compiled, the compile:compile doesn't run, and the tests can succeed.

Workaround was proc:none to the javac compiler args as described here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    <proc:none/>
                    <Xlint/>
                    <Xlint:-path/>
                    <verbose />
                </compilerArguments>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer showed me the right direction: set *exclude-unlisted-classes* to **true** and add the entities manually for each persistenceUnit

Answer (score 2):

This http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/entity-class-generation-td5542168.html solved it for me. Just adding -proc:none to the compiler options in NetBeans removed that obtuse error message.

Answer (score 0):

Using

I only needed to add one for my testPu (In memory Derby for jUnit tests, rather than needing to actually use Glassfish / MySQL installation). This made the testPU distinct from the Runtime PU in connection and subpackage, but otherwise did not affect my entity definitions.

Answer (score 0):

include the entity classes for each persistence unit manually 
should not include the same class in more than a persistence unit.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It doesn't make much sense to answer such an old question which in fact has many answers and marked answered as well. Also you need to read [this section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) of Help center.

Answer (score 0):

Two persistence units within the same persistence.xml might be using the same entity. So either delete one of the persistence unit or change entities accessed by both the units.
To do this open persistence.xml file and scroll down to see another units that you've added. Modify it according to your requirements.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add to persistence.xml file line

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```