# How to write JUNIT test case for mocking?

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have the method similar to following structure.

```
method1(Object obj,byte[] myarray)
{
    mymanager.dbcall1();
    mymanager2.dbcall2();
}
```

Now I want to write the JUNIT test case which can actually mock these managers who are doing the dbcalls ?Finally I want to compare the results. These managers are available only at run time of the application.

Comment: the class that holds method1, does it have getters and setters for mymanager or mymanager2? How are they created at runtime?

Comment: managed by spring as @Resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to test `method1()`? If so, I assume that you have a setter for `mymanager` in the enclosing class, which will enable you to (using Mockito):

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
    MyClass my = new MyClass();
    MyManager mgr = mock( MyManager.class );
    my.setManager( mgr );

    // Similar for mymanager2
}
```

Then all method calls on `mgr` will just return null. If you need other return values, the `doReturn(...).when( mgr ).dbcall1()` construct can be used.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I searched on stack overflow and found pretty much something that someone has asked before:

[Testing an EJB with JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469751/testing-an-ejb-with-junit)

It's based on EJB but we don't know what you are using right now, but this might have some common principles.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need some dependency injection.  There are many ways to accomplish this, but here's a simple one:

```
private I_DatabaseManager mymanager = null;

method1(Object obj,byte[] myarray)
{
    getDatabaseManager().dbcall1();
    getDatabaseManager().dbcall2();
}

private I_DatabaseManager getDatabaseManager() {
    if (mymanager == null) {
          return getProductionImplementationOfDatabaseManager();
    }
    return mymanager;
}

protected void setDatabaseManagerImplementation(I_DatabaseManager newImplementation) {
    mymanager = newImplementation;
}
```

Then, in your test code you can create a mock class which implements the I_DatabaseManager interface and set this mock implementaion in your test.